# could not disconnect socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcpclient

Here is my tcpClient class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class tcpClient
{
private String _ip;
private int _port;
private Socket _clientSocket;

public tcpClient(String IP, int Port)
{
    _ip = IP;
    _port = Port;
}

public boolean createSocket()
{
    boolean retSt = false;

    try
    {
        _clientSocket = new Socket(this._ip, this._port);
        retSt = true;
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retSt;
}

public boolean disposeSocket()
{
    boolean retSt = false;

    try
    {
        _clientSocket.shutdownInput();
        _clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
        _clientSocket.close();

        retSt = true;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retSt;
}

public boolean isConnected()
{
    return _clientSocket.isConnected();
}
}
```

Here is my main method:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Date;

    public class cos
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    tcpClient client = new tcpClient("192.168.10.39", 1234);
    client.createSocket();
    System.out.println(client.isConnected());
    client.disposeSocket();
    System.out.println(client.isConnected());
    client.createSocket();
    System.out.println(client.isConnected());
    client.disposeSocket();
    System.out.println(client.isConnected());
        }
    }
```

Here is my console output:

```
true
true
true
true
```

Why couldn't i disconnect from server?

Comment: disposesocket is running and closing the tcp with _clientSocket.close(); and you are resetting the retSt to true when it closes. so it is returning true

Comment: no! i am not returning retSt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected%28%29):

> Note: Closing a socket doesn't clear its connection state, which means
>   this method will return true for a closed socket (see isClosed()) if
>   it was successfuly connected prior to being closed.

Comment: Ok! Is my way right to close the socket? First shutdown input and output channels and then close socket.

Comment: yes, though calling `close()` will automatically close the input/output streams, so you don't explicitly need to close them. also see [`isClosed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isClosed()) for wheter the socket is closed or not

Comment: @petre You should close the outermost output stream or writer that you've wrapped around the socket. You don't need to do the shutdowns either.